# Spring Boot KeyCloak not invoking success handler

Tags: spring-security, keycloak

I am using Spring Boot KeyCloak in my application to connect with KeyCloak. However I have a custom success handler which is not being invoked. I am not sure why. here is my code:

`SecurityConfiguration.java`:

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Override
    protected KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter(authenticationManagerBean());
        filter.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy());
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler());
        filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failureHandler());
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
    }

    @NotNull
    @Bean
    public KeyCloakAuthSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        return new KeyCloakAuthSuccessHandler(new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
    }

    @NotNull
    @Bean
    public KeyCloakAuthFailureHandler failureHandler() {
        return new KeyCloakAuthFailureHandler();
    }

}
```

And in my `KeyCloakAuthSuccessHandler.java`, I have:

```
@Slf4j
public class KeyCloakAuthSuccessHandler extends KeycloakAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper mapper;

    public KeyCloakAuthSuccessHandler(AuthenticationSuccessHandler fallback) {
        super(fallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.error("inside success handler");
        if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof KeycloakPrincipal) {
            AccessToken token = ((KeycloakPrincipal<?>) authentication.getPrincipal()).getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken();
            // do other stuff
        }
    }
}
```

The above code doesn't invoked the success handler however a similar failure handler is working and getting invoked.

Comment: Why you annotate class with @Slf4j ?

Comment: for logging things in my success handler

Comment: @mifol68042 did you try testing by not passing bearer/basic(whichever configured) header once and once with it? does it not go through the success handler even in both scenarios?? since the code looks quite right.

Comment: @YeshwanthVShenoy it skips the success handler when i pass the header but invokes it when i don't pass the header(redirects to keycloak and then after auth invokes the handler with auth info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed over the comments, this is because the success handler is not invoked during non-interactive(non-human ways - bearer/basic) login of Keycloak. If you want to invoke success handler each time irrespective of the way of login, write a custom `KeycloakAuthencticationProcessingFilter` by extending the same and change [this line](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/adapters/oidc/spring-security/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/springsecurity/filter/KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java#L196) from the original one by over-riding it.

A rough example will look like:

```
public class CustomKeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter extends KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    
    public CustomKeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(authenticationManager);
    }

    public CustomKeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, RequestMatcher requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher) {
        super(authenticationManager, requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Line of importance down here
        if (authResult instanceof KeycloakAuthenticationToken) {
            super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
            return;
        }
        // whatever spring-boot-keycloak does copy paste here
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to write your own KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter using your KeyCloakAuthSuccessHandler.

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/adapters/oidc/spring-security/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/springsecurity/filter/KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java

You can't inject your KeyCloakAuthSuccessHandler.

Comment: I have already written a processing filter. Please check the code above. Its done via using `@Bean` annotation in the `websecurityconfig` itself

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: You have to debug to see what really happens.